# JNI error - cant call [method] when using CallVoidMethod

Tags: java, android, c, callback, java-native-interface

My goal is to have an infinite loop in the c code that does a callback passing a `String` to a Java function. The Java function then uses the `String` to update the contents of a textbox. The problem is the callback attempt is generating the following error:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon.updateSign(java.lang.String) on instance of java.lang.Class<com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon>
```

The C code:

```
/* return current time in milliseconds */
static double
now_ms(void)
{
    struct timespec res;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &res);
    return 1000.0*res.tv_sec + (double)res.tv_nsec/1e6;
}
jstring  Java_com_example_helloneon_HelloNeon_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                    jobject thiz ) {
    int seconsaperline = 3;
    static double t0 = 0;
    if (t0 == 0) { t0 = now_ms(); }
    //jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/helloneon/HelloNeon");
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,thiz) ;

    jmethodID timerId2 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls,
                                             "updateSign", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "line nnnn");

    while (true) {
        if (((now_ms() - t0) * .001) >= seconsaperline) {
            t0 = now_ms();
        }
        //generates:
        // JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon.updateSign(java.lang.String) on instance of java.lang.Class<com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon>
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, cls, timerId2, jstr);
    }
    //return jstr;

}
```

The java code:

```
public class HelloNeon extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_neon);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.text_view_hello_neon);
        /*
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_hello_neon))
                .setText(stringFromJNI());  */

        new doWork().execute("");
    }


    /*called from c code*/
    @Keep
    public  void updateSign(final String  line) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                HelloNeon.this.tv.setText(line);
            }
        });

    }
    public native String stringFromJNI();



    public class doWork extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {


            while (true) {

                stringFromJNI();

            }


            // return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] passedData) {
        }

    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-neon");
    }
}
```

In this stripped-down version, I'd expect the text box to keep displaying the same string because the same `string` is passed each `callback`. instead the `app` is `crashing`. the stack trace gives the following error

```
2019-09-05 20:42:10.330 8764-8791/com.example.helloneon A/ample.helloneo: runtime.cc:566] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon.updateSign(java.lang.String) on instance of java.lang.Class<com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon>
2019-09-05 20:42:10.330 8764-8791/com.example.helloneon A/ample.helloneo: runtime.cc:566]     in call to CallVoidMethod
2019-09-05 20:42:10.330 8764-8791/com.example.helloneon A/ample.helloneo: runtime.cc:566]     from java.lang.String com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon.stringFromJNI()
```

edit: 
per a suggestion in the c code I replaced

```
jmethodID timerId2 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls,
                                                 "updateSign", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

with

```
jmethodID timerId2 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, thiz,
                                                 "updateSign", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

and then with

```
jmethodID timerId2 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (jclass) thiz,
                                             "updateSign", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

both changes yeilded the following error

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jclass has wrong type: com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon
2019-09-06 17:31:42.752 9787-9826/com.example.helloneon A/ample.helloneo: runtime.cc:566]     in call to GetMethodID
2019-09-06 17:31:42.752 9787-9826/com.example.helloneon A/ample.helloneo: runtime.cc:566]     from java.lang.String com.example.helloneon.HelloNeon.stringFromJNI()

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You need an instance of the class, not the class itself, as the second parameter. Probably `thiz`.

Comment: As the second parameter *of the API that gave you the error message.* Surely this is obvious? Not of another API that was working perfectly already. Your thought processes are impenetrable.

Comment: Is JNI passing an instance of the wrong class type to the native function!? ideas to fix this please

Comment: No, *you* are passing a class instead of an instance to `CallVoidMethod()`, exactly as the error message already told you, and as I already told you, two days ago. *And* I've already told you how to fix it. Two days ago.

Comment: Thank you, but I thought when I replaced the second parameter with thiz instead of cls that I was following your suggested fix. I understand how the original code was wrong. I don't understand how the jobj thiz is not an instance of the class

Comment: `thiz` *is* an instance of the class. You have everything back to front here.Your problem was `CallVoidMethod(env, cls, timerId2, jstr)` when it should have been `CallVoidMethod(env, thiz, timerId2, jstr)`. You 'fixed' the wrong line of code, you ignored what the error message was plainly telling you, and you didn't follow what I wrote either.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that works. below is functional c code

```
jstring  Java_com_example_helloneon_HelloNeon_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                             jobject thiz ) {

    int seconsaperline = 3;
    static double t0 = 0;
    if (t0 == 0) { t0 = now_ms(); }

    //originally incorrectly used just this in place of next 2
    jclass clz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, thiz);

    //fix added following line, passing jniHelperClz to GetMethodID:
    jclass jniHelperClz = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, clz);

    //fix added following line, passing mainActivityObj to CallVoidMethod:
    jclass mainActivityObj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, thiz);

    jmethodID timerId2 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jniHelperClz,
                                             "updateSign", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");


    jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "line nnnn");
    while (true) {
        if (((now_ms() - t0) * .001) >= seconsaperline) {
            t0 = now_ms();
        }

         (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, mainActivityObj, timerId2, jstr);
    }
    //return jstr;

}
```

Comment: The result of `NewGlobalRef` is not a `jclass` but a `jobject`. You don't need to waste a `NewGlobalRef` on this, or indeed leak one as you are doing here. You were already given a solution. Several times. You need to stop guessing.